# Load Control Function in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-s3, architecture, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

An AWS Step Function State Machine has a Lambda Function at its core, that does heavy writes to a S3 bucket. When the State Machine gets a usage spike, the function starts failing due to S3 blocking further requests (`com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate.`). This obviously leads to failures of the state machine execution as a whole and it takes the whole system some minutes to fully recover.

I looked into the [AWS Lambda Function Scaling Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html) and found out, that when we reduce the *reserved concurrency* flag, the function will start to return `429` status codes, as soon as it can't handle new events.

So my idea to load control the function execution can be summarized as following:

1. Set the *reserved concurrency* to some lower value.
2. Catching the `429` errors in the step function and [retrying with a backoff rate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-examples).

I'd like to have feedback from you guys, on the following aspects:

a. Does my approach make sense or am I missing some obvious better way? I first thought of looking into managing the load with AWS SQS or some execution wide locking/semaphore but didn't really see any further.
b. Is there maybe another way to tackle the issue from the S3 side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach worked well for me:

```
States:
 MyFunction:
  Type: Task
  End: true
  Resource: "..."
  Retry:
   - ErrorEquals:
      - TooManyRequestsException
     IntervalSeconds: 30
     MaxAttemtps: 5
     BackoffRate: 2
```